# Inheriting or sharing directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives: A and B. They're very similar. I want directive B to inherit the controller in directive A.

In other words, the same function used for `controller:` in A's directive definition object needs to also be the `controller:` function used in B's directive definition object.

Aside from a copy/paste of the `controller:` function, how I use the same function in both A and B's definition?

Comment: Does that function do something specific to the view model or is it a common purpose function, if so just create a service and add that function there, and use the service in both the places. How ever you can use prototypical inheritance to create the inherited controller, but are you looking to inherit the functions on the scope or on the controller instance?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are just regular JS functions, so, you can use prototyping:

```
function BaseController(){
    this.commonFunct = function(){
        ...
    }
}

function CtrlA(){
}
CtrlA.prototype = BaseController

function CtrlB(){
}
CtrlB.prototype = BaseController
```

this works with `controllerAs` syntax, when your controller is exposed to scope under some name, say `ctrl`. Then `$scope.ctrl.commonFunct` (more generic, works from any place of controller) or `this.commonFunct` (can be used in controller's instance methods, where `this` is controller itself) can be used to refer the function.

That works if you declare both controllers in one module as named functions. If they are declared in different modules, you can use mixin-like way with `$controller`:

```
// Base module
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('Base', []);

  function BaseController($scope, <injectables>, that) {
    that.commonFunct = function() {
    };
  }

  angular.module('Base').controller('BaseController',
    ['$scope', '...', BaseController]);
})();

// Module that inherits functionality
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('Derived', ['Base']);

  function DerivedController($scope, $controller, ...) {
    $controller('BaseController', {
      '$scope' : $scope,
      ...
      'that' : this
    });

    // this.commonFunct is available
  }

  angular.module('Derived').controller('DerivedController',
    ['$scope', '$controller', '...', DerivedController]);
})();
```

MHO: I suggest to use named functions for declaring controllers / services and directives as it is more natural, JS way of doing things. Also, I like `controllerAs` syntax much as it helps to distinguish data, stored directly in scope (like `$scope.data`) with controller's methods (they all are stored in one scope's named object, like `$scope.ctrl`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you don't really want to inherit controllers. You want to use one controller in 2 different directives.
If that's the case, just declare the controller function, and pass it to both directive definition objects as a function or a string.

Comment: Right. Let me clarify: both directives are in the same module, but declared in separate files. What I ended up doing is exposing the `controller` as a function on a factory, injecting that factoring into both directives, and setting the `controller` on the directive definition objects to the function exposed on the factory instance. Maybe I should be using a service though? Still unclear to me when to use which.

Comment: Controller is just a function, hence you don't really need a service/factory. Write your controller in a separate file, and make sure to include it in your web-page. Then, just pass the function name to the DDO of both directives. That way, you just re-use a function.